# SignalR how to avoid connecting twice

Tags: jquery, signalr, signalr-hub

In my application once I logged in I redirect to Home page where I have the following script:

```
// Defining a connection to the server hub.
        var myHub = $.connection.myHub;
        // Setting logging to true so that we can see whats happening in the browser console log. [OPTIONAL]
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        // Start the hub
        $.connection.hub.start();

        myHub.client.newMessageReceived = function (message) {
            alert(message);
        }
```

In my Hub.cs server I have:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

            // here do other stuff...

            return base.OnConnected();
        }
```

The first time I get into the Home page I can see that I get a `connectionId` but If I reload again the page I get a different one and that's happening because the jquery script it's being called again.

> How can I detect in my client if Im already connected so I dont `start()` the hub everytime I refresh that page?

Comment: Save the `connectionId` on `localStorage`...check if you already have a value for the `connectionId` on your `localStorage`, if you have it, then do not execute that piece of code, if not, execute that code....just an `if-else` solution...

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. It's a different connection, so a new connectionId. It's pretty hard to link the two together - there's not much difference between opening a new tab whilst closing the old and reloading. Any suggestion you have will have a downside. You are asking how to implement a flawed solution - What is your underlying requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar scenario where a redirect was kicking off another request to connect to SignalR - I solved by checking the `connection.state` and filtering out requests unless the connection was in a `Disconnected` state. I was using angular + rxjs, but hopefully similar principles still apply:

#### In the hub service

```js
this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${environment.apiUrl}/hubRoute`)
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Warning)
      .build();
```

#### And then in the request to connect to SignalR

```js
filter(() => this.hubService.connection.state === HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
// safe to call hubService.connection.start();
```

Hope that helps someone else stumbling upon the same thing!